# How do I make a function run again on a key press?

Tags: matlab

I have a function that displays a graph with some random elements. I want to have it so that when the user presses a certain key the function runs again, redistributing these random elements on the graph. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap this within a `while` loop and using [`ginput`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html).  Put your function call within a `while` loop, use `ginput` and poll for a keystroke, and while this key is being pushed, keep going.  Something like this, assuming that your figure is open after each call to the function:

```
while true
    %// Generate random data
    %// Call function
    %// Open figure

    %// Get a key from the user
    [~,~,b] = ginput(1);

    %// If you push C or c, then continue
    if b == 67 || b == 99
        continue;
    else %// Else, get out
        break;
    end
end
```

Comment: OP should really be setting the `'KeyPressFcn'` callback for a figure.

Comment: @jucestain - Whatever they want to choose, let them choose it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, This was perfect for what I needed it to do. Thank you!

Comment: Hello! No problem at all. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You want to set a key press callback for a figure you're using in a script by using the `KeyPressFcn` like so:

```
h = figure('KeyPressFcn',@testcallback);
```

Then place the following in a function `testcallback.m` file (you can also use a function handle):

```
function testcallback(hObject,callbackdata)
    % Check to make sure key pressed is the escape key
    if (strcmp(callbackdata.Key,'escape'))
        % Do whatever processing you want
        imshow(rand(40));
    end
end
```

When you run the script, a figure will appear. Everytime you press `escape`, the function will fire:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using the `input()` function in MATLAB allows you to prompt and ask a user for input. You can use this function to prompt the user to enter a key, when this key is entered, your function can be called and re-run.

Documentation on this can be found on the [Mathworks website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html)

Comment: `input` steals focus from the figure, while `ginput` doesn't; in this case @rayryeng's solution is better.

Comment: @Setsu - I was just about to write that as a comment.

Comment: @Setsu - BTW, come visit us in our MATLAB StackOverflow chat room! I just set it up a few days ago... whenever you have time!  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave